# Starting another shell script without waiting

Tags: bash, shell

I have two scripts script1.sh and script2.sh. I want to start second script from first script but don't want to block the first script or wait for the completion of execution of second script.

script1.sh :

```
echo "inside first script"
script2.sh &
exit 0
```

script2.sh :

```
sleep 1m
echo "inside script2"
```

what i want is that once script2 is started from within script1, script1.sh should exit, and should not for script2 to complete. but i am not able to achieve this.

Can someone help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: _but i am not able to achieve this_ -- could you elaborate?

Comment: What you have is exactly correct.  Why do you think it's not working?  Perhaps your prompt is being displayed before "inside script2".  Try executing a command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setsid` command to start a new program in a new session:

Script 1:

```
#!/bin/sh
(setsid "./script2.sh" &);
```

Script 2:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Whatever
```

---

**Edit**: Actually, it looks like your current solution is already working.